# Can my symbol be exactly at the middle of mu button?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have my "+" that is a little bellow the center in my button. How can he be right in the center? Here is my code: [Code](https://snack.expo.dev/@ljacquet/exemple-buton-plus)

Comment: add ` marginBottom: -7` on Text style

Comment: A proper [mre] of your issue belongs directly inside your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Wrapper `TouchableOpacity` - should be `justifyContent: "center"`
2. For `Text` need to set `fontFamily`. Or set  `lineHeight` and `justifyContent`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display a div or container inside of another first use display flex than justify content, align-items and make sure padding is set to 0 or to a value than you want

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).